# Issue with Mac OSX Terminal, shows special character codes like space, brakets

Tags: macos, utf-8, terminal

I have recently used "localedef" command to add support for the multiple locales.
After doing that I noticed on my terminal for every "space, backslash, forward slash etc" it is showing UTF code like <0200> <002d> etc.

I really want to disable this behaviour as it is really difficult to read commands.

For more clarity please see attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been caused due to `localedef` I am able to confirm post getting a reply from Apple Support team.

As per the `support team` instruction I created a `New User Account` and checked terminal. With new account terminal worked well.

Best solution is 
`New User Account` if we want avoid any manual effort. 
Otherwise you should compare `ENV variables` of Old account and New account and fix the issue.